# How to resolve "Build failed with error code: 1" when running ionic?

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm

When creating an ionic project the following error(s) occur:

```
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/fernandolucio/tesfff/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/fernandolucio/tesfff/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/fernandolucio/tesfff/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v10.14.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/fernandolucio/.npm/_logs/2018-12-23T00_18_35_148Z-debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

    npm i exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more 
    information.
```

How can these errors be resolved?  I am using:

- ionic version 4.6.0
- node version 10.14.2
- npm version 6.5.0

Comment: You don't happen to be running the app at the same of the install? Or have a sub folder open in a terminal? The error would suggest another process is locking the file / folder

Comment: it's possible that it's python 2

Comment: npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Not Found: phynton@lastest

Comment: You need to install SAAS externally with sudo command so it will work after SAAS install.

Answer (score 3):

my issue is resolved by using the following command

~ npm install node-sass@latest